# Powershell -Confirm:$Y

Tags: c#, powershell

Hello Fellow programmers, can someone show me the way to pass -Confirm:$Y using a c# code.
Here is my C# Code which doesn't accept the -Confirm parameter.

```
PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
PSCommand command = new PSCommand();
command.AddCommand("Remove-MailContact");
string DisplayName = "UniqueValue112";
command.AddParameter("Identity", DisplayName);
command.AddParameter("Confirm", true);
```

The equivalent powershell code is

```
Remove-MailContact -Identity $DisplayName -Confirm:$Y
```

Can someone tell me how to pass equivalent to -Confirm:$Y using C#?

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `-Confirm $Y` ?

Comment: I want to suppress the "Are you sure you want to delete" prompt. Only way to do that with powershell is using switch -Confirm:$Y

Answer (score 7):

You want to set the value of `-Confirm` to false.

```
command.AddParameter("Confirm", false);
```

In PowerShell commands, **`-Confirm:$false`** is the correct way to do this.

The reason `-Confirm:$y` works is that `$y` is (usually) an undefined variable, which evaluates to `$null`, which becomes `$false` when cast to Boolean.  Obviously, this will fail in mysterious and hard-to-debug ways if some part of your script sets the variable `$y` to a non-null value.

A note about the syntax: `-Parameter:$value` is equivalent to `-Parameter $value` for most PowerShell parameters.  The former is required for `[switch]` parameters such as `-Confirm`, because they normally don't take a value, and thus will not bind to the next token on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following:

```
command.AddParameter("Confirm", new SwitchParameter(false));
```

This should work fine :)